# Reading from CSV and storing in a Vector

Tags: c++, csv, omnet++

Consider I have the following csv file:

```
10.0.0.26
10.0.0.30
10.0.0.34
10.0.0.38
...
...
```

Consider I have a vector:

```
std::vector<L3Address> destAddresses;
```

I want a piece of code the will read the above csv file till the very last address and store each of that address in the above vector.

```
std::ifstream  data("data.csv");
while(//till the end of file){
//read from csv
//write to vector
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
std::ifstream  data("data.csv");
while(std::getline(data,std::string value){
destAddresses.push_back(value);
}
```

But this isn't working somehow.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: he did an std::move(home work);

Comment: if you want a piece of code there are 3 ways : 1) find existing piece of code 2) write it yourself 3) have someone else write it for you. for (1) use google, SO does not provide (3) as far as i know.

Comment: ok ok. I should have been clear. my mistake.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please review

Comment: What do you mean it "isn't working somehow"? Is there a compilation error? If so, have you read it? What does it say? It would be useful to include it in your question.
Or, it compiles, but crashes? When and how?

Comment: std::getline(data,std::string value) - as far as i know you cant declare variable inside function call

Comment: You need to convert your `std::string value` into an `L3Address` object before adding it to a vector of `L3Address` objects.  Since you didn't provide any info about what `L3Address` is, we cannot help you.

Comment: @JustinRandall L3Address is used as a variable in "Omnet++" a network simulation tool that has c++ on its back end. Every node in the simulation has an ip address of the type L3Address. again apologies for not being clear enough.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews forget the comment it was the wrong question, sorry. I deleted it. Il will delete this one in a few minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go look at the documentation of [`L3Address`](https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/doxy/classinet_1_1_l3_address.html) (note 1). Here we can see a function  `bool L3Address::tryParse(const char * str)`, which will try to interpret a C-string as an address, and tell you if it succeded.

```
std::ifstream  data("data.csv");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(data, line) {
    L3Address addr;
    if (addr.tryParse(line.c_str())) {
        destAddresses.push_back(addr);
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: handle malformed address
    }
}
```

Note 1: The tooling that generated this documentation is formatting it very badly, so it is excusable that you couldn't get here yourself.

Comment: Works exactly like it should. Appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Your example doesn't seem to compile. Besides the missing parenthesis the `getline` function you are using requires a variable reference as the second argument. Hence, you should fix your code by defining the `value` variable before use.

Additionally to construct the `L3Address` you can benefit from the constructor accepting `const char*`.

```
std::ifstream  data("data.csv");
std::string value;
while(std::getline(data,value))
{
    destAddresses.emplace_back(value.c_str());
}
```

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't have to be an _alias_, just implicitly constructible (convertible) from `std::string`. And since the question is tagged with `omnet++`, they are most likely talking about this class: https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/networklayer/common/L3Address.h which is only explicitly constructible from `const char *`.

Comment: @Attila You are correct. However it seems to be a different type constructible from `const char*` - updated my answer.

Comment: @Dusteh there is nothing wrong with your answer. The above answer just puts some light on "Omnet++" (a tag that I mentioned in my question). Thank you though